# Django data transfer sqllite - >> models - >> html

Tags: python, django, sqlite, pythonanywhere

There is a separate script that works with some sites and writes the selected data to the database. Here is its part associated with the database.
conn = sqlite3.connect("bgg1.db")
conn.text_factory = str

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
# delete 
cursor.execute("""DROP TABLE yres;""")
sql_command = """
CREATE TABLE yres ( 
name   VARCHAR(100), 
track  VARCHAR(100), 
number VARCHAR(100),
point  VARCHAR(100));"""
cursor.execute(sql_command)

cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO yres (name, track, number, point) VALUES (?, ?, 
 ?, ?)", 
 (str(td_text[1]),str(td_text[5]),str(td_text[6]),str(df['attribute.name'] 
 [0])))
conn.commit()
```

Then I have a jango project with a connected template .. and everything else .. and I want to output the data to an html file .. I don’t know how to do it through models or how. And how to start my script when starting a project? Run automatic model generation

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb    
$ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Created some model .. and then I do not know what to do

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class AuthGroup(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=80)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group'


class AuthGroupPermissions(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey('AuthPermission', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group_permissions'
        unique_together = (('group', 'permission'),)


class AuthPermission(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_permission'
        unique_together = (('content_type', 'codename'),)


class AuthUser(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'


class AuthUserGroups(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user_groups'
        unique_together = (('user', 'group'),)


class AuthUserUserPermissions(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(AuthPermission, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user_user_permissions'
        unique_together = (('user', 'permission'),)


class DjangoAdminLog(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    action_time = models.DateTimeField()
    object_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    object_repr = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    change_message = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    action_flag = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_admin_log'


class DjangoContentType(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_content_type'
        unique_together = (('app_label', 'model'),)


class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applied = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_migrations'


class DjangoSession(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    session_data = models.TextField()
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_session'


class YresAuthor(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_death = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'yres_author'


class YresBook(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(YresAuthor, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField()
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=13)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'yres_book'


class YresBookGenre(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    book = models.ForeignKey(YresBook, models.DO_NOTHING)
    genre = models.ForeignKey('YresGenre', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'yres_book_genre'
        unique_together = (('book', 'genre'),)


class YresBookinstance(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32)
    book = models.ForeignKey(YresBook, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    imprint = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    due_back = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'yres_bookinstance'


class YresGenre(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: This is far too broad. You should go through the tutorial, which shows you exactly how to write views that query your database and render templates.

Comment: i would recommend going through the django tutorial or the djangogirls tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I figured everything out !!) First you need to create a model, then migrate it to the database, and then write the data to the database through the script. Well, then connect the models in the submission file and then in the html itself. If anyone needs this link is not a resource that helped me figure it out.

[enter link description here](https://metanit.com/python/django/5.4.php)